# Localhost: OS or Computer

Tags: networking, localhost

The `localhost`-address (`127.0.0.1`); is this an addresses supported by the OS or is this the address for the computer?

I want to know this because I want to make a program in Java to use as a `file-transfer-bridge` between the main OS and a session in `VirtualBox`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why so many `close`s?? Is there a dup?

Comment: because this is the wrong place for such questions.

Comment: Serverfault or Superuser .. unfortunately SO is not a one stop shop :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 2):

OS

The only "computer" address is the MAC address, but even that is specific to the network device. Your virtual box OS will most likely link to a virtual network device with a unique MAC address.

Comment: So I have to use in Java: `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`?

Comment: Correct, that's how you would get that address

Comment: In the case of a virtual machine the localhost address refers to the guest virtual machine not the host machine.  There's no way inside the VM OS (without using proprietary tools) to get the host machine's address.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot where I saw this before (probably on SU), but try the address `10.0.0.2` from within the virtualbox machine, it should be the address of the host machine (the real machine).

Comment: I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is a reserved domain name used to refer to 'this computer'  localhost will always resolve to 127.0.0.1 (on IPv4).  Check out [Localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) and [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback).